# Cygwin causes a Java "package does not exist" error

Tags: java, unix, cygwin, gnu

I'm compiling a Java project via a makefile, and my collaborator and I have different machines (he has Apple, I have Windows). I'm using Cygwin to run the makefile on my machine, but the Java won't compile - even though it compiles on my collaborator's machine. The command that works for him is of the form

> javac -cp "./stem/java/lib/*:./stem/java/bin/Project.jar" -d
>   ./stem/java/bin ./stem/java/src/Project/A.java
>   ./stem/java/src/Project/B.java ./stem/java/src/Project/C.java
>   ./stem/java/src/Project/D.java ./stem/java/src/Project/E.java
>   ./stem/java/src/Project/F.java

Running the same command on my machine yields errors of the form

> .\stem\java\src\Project\A.java:460: error: package GRB does not exist

Where GRB is the Gurobi external .jar which is included in the /lib/ folder and is used many times in the code.

I then tried to run the same command through the Windows command line rather than Cygwin, but it gave the same error message

I then tried to change the escape characters from "/" to "\" as was given in the error message, but that didn't work either. In Windows cmd the error was the same as before, but in Cygwin it was:

> javac: file not found: .stemjavasrcProjectA.java

The error is obviously some problem with how Cygwin runs the makefile (it can't be a problem with the build path of the external jar, or else it wouldn't work for my collaborator), but what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are running under Cygwin, you are still invoking the Windows version/distribution of Java.

The Windows version of Java requires that you use the semicolon (;) character as the classpath separator (as opposed to the colon (:) used on Linux and Mac).  So change the command in your makefile to

> javac -cp "./stem/java/lib/*;./stem/java/bin/Project.jar"...

Comment: That said, you should investigate using a more modern 'build tool', such as maven or gradle - once your project gets a bit more complex, make will be a very clunky way to build your project.